# PostgreSQL connect timeout recommendations

Tags: postgresql, libpq, libpqxx

I found this at [official postresql documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-connect.html)

> connect_timeout
>   Maximum wait for connection, in seconds (write as a
>   decimal integer string). Zero or not specified means wait
>   indefinitely. It is not recommended to use a timeout of less than 2
>   seconds.

Why not less than 2 seconds?

Comment: It's just a recommendation, not a rule. A network retry or slow latency connection would be a lot more likely to fail.

Comment: Drive-by note: when PQconnectStart + PQconnectPoll is used by your postgres library (for example haskell's postgresql-simple uses those), then the connect_timeout is disregarded. So always check your timeouts if they work for real. On an intranet setting, I would recommend setting the `tcp_user_timeout` connection param that will efficiently detect both connect-time and in-progress connection problems. If fail-fast is your primary goal.